# Ms SQL date range query: month to month OK but whole year incorrect results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query below that returns the correct results when executed month by month. i.e. 1jan -31st jan, 2nd feb - 28th feb, 1st march -31st march.. etc etc.

but when i set historydate>= '2017-01-01' to capture the whole year, it returns completely wrong results. Any ideas? I'm on mssql

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       cl.id AS id, cl.[KEY] AS issuekey,
       MAX(historyDate) AS releaseDate,
       m.issueType,
       m.priority
FROM d_jira_changelog cl
     JOIN d_jira_changelog_items ci ON ci.historyId = cl.historyId
     JOIN d_jira_main m ON m.id = cl.id
WHERE(ci.changeitemfrom = 'Phase1'
      AND ci.changeItemTo = 'Phase2')
     AND changeItemField = 'status'
     AND m.projectkey IN('ABC', 'CBA', 'XYZ', 'YOYO')
     AND historydate >= '2017-01-01'
GROUP BY cl."id", cl."key", m.issueType, m.priority;
```

Comment: We don't have your data nor any knowledge of what correct or incorrect results would look like. All we have is your query, which we could try to pull apart to divine the *intent*, but **we already know that the query is wrong**.

Comment: point taken. will post the results in a sec

Answer (score 0):

Issue Seem to Be IN WHERE Clause If column historydate Is Datetime Then Surely you will not get any record based on this WHERE Clause **historydate >= '2017-01-01'**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       cl.id AS id, cl.[KEY] AS issuekey,
       MAX(historyDate) AS releaseDate,
       m.issueType,
       m.priority
FROM d_jira_changelog cl
     JOIN d_jira_changelog_items ci ON ci.historyId = cl.historyId
     JOIN d_jira_main m ON m.id = cl.id
WHERE(ci.changeitemfrom = 'Phase1'
      AND ci.changeItemTo = 'Phase2')
     AND changeItemField = 'status'
     AND m.projectkey IN('ABC', 'CBA', 'XYZ', 'YOYO')
     CONVERT(NVARCHAR,historydate,111) >= CONVERT(NVARCHAR,'2017-01-01',111) 
GROUP BY cl."id", cl."key", m.issueType, m.priority;
```